# $N$-body simulation in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, simulations, galaxies, three-body-problem

How would one perform an $N$-body simulation in General Relativity (GR) for something like galaxy formation or galactic dynamics?

Suppose one wants to simulate the rotation curve $v(r)$ for galaxies with an $N$-body simulation, and wants to do it in the framework of GR / the Einstein equations.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific than that. If the conditions are mild than all you need is Newtonian gravity plus some corrections. If the situation is complex (like dynamics of black hole collision, or star collapse) then one needs to discretize full GR equations and this is not simple at all...

Comment: @Marek: added some context.

Comment: This isn't a standard reply. As for any physical problem there 10 different approaches with increasing complexity possible. When solving hydrogen atom in QM, you can just solve classical electron picture, you can add relativistic effects, you can add spin-interactions, nucleus composition, QFT effects, etc., etc. Most of these are completely irrelevant for standard purposes. That's why I am asking again: what level of complexity are you after? There's no one single correct approach to numerical GR, there are dozens. If you don't know answer to this then you have no question...

Comment: @Marek: suppose one wants to simulate v(r) for galaxies with N-bodies, and wants to do it in the framework of GR / Einstein equations.

Comment: okay, now *that* is some context. It would be nice if you added this (and more) information to the question.

Comment: The question is still awfully broad. Are you looking for some references on how to enter the field of numerical GR? Looking for references for particular recipes? Looking for known results?

Comment: @Willie: yes, I'm also interested in references!

Comment: Have a look at the [universe sandbox](http://universesandbox.com/). Everything is classical gravity though.

Comment: For galaxy rotation curves, I'm guessing that low order post-Newtonian terms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_post-Newtonian_formalism) are sufficient as corrections (as pointed out by @Marek). For formation, I would guess that having accurate equations of state would be far more important than any gravitational corrections.

Comment: From a technical/computational point of view, is it known how to do N-body simulations in GR?

Comment: There are loads of articles on this, see for example http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Light++** It is not open source but you can try to contact the author, Werner Benger.

A few years ago we have access to the source code of 'light++'. Not anymore :(

[Light++ Raytracer!](https://web.archive.org/web/20110814074723/http://www.photon.at/~werner/light/)   (general relativistic raytracing)

[Simulation of a Black Hole by Raytracing](https://web.archive.org/web/20160626225920/http://photon.at/~werner/bh/index.en.html)

[The Black Earth](https://web.archive.org/web/20110909024110/http://www.photon.at/~werner/black-earth/index.en.html)

About the simulation of galactic close encounters, or a n-body general simulation, under the constraints of GR I found nothing.

EDIT ADD
"I found nothing" can be read like this "there is not a single software package" because, AFAIK,
*no one knows how to apply GR in the computation of planetary and galaxy dynamics* (small scale with matter).
The [Zeldovich approximation](http://fisica.usac.edu.gt/public/curccaf_proc/borganihtml/node4.html) is used in the linearization of GR (with caveats):

> and has been successfully applied to describe the large scale
>   clustering in the distribution of galaxy clusters. ..However, within
>   the Zeldovich prescription, after a pancake forms in correspondence of
>   crossing of particle orbits, such particles continue travelling along
>   straight lines, ..

I think that your aim is hopeless because GR is around since 1917 and no one succeeded.
Interesting questions, imo:
How close to the reality  are the simulations that are performed with Newtonian codes.
What kind of problems we may expect if we are gonna try to do a simulation code.

EDIT ADD end

Comment: NOTE: Dead link. `http://www.photon.at/~werner/light/` returns **Forbidden** - You don't have permission to access /~werner/light/ on this server.

Comment: @ja72 there is a related library [here](http://www.fiberbundle.net/doc/index.html)

Comment: @ja72: Archive.org'd the dead links.

Comment: Interesting, but raytracing is most definitely _not_ n-body simulation!  However, if that is what you want, then try this tutorial with c source code: http://www.madore.org/~david/math/kerr.html

Answer (score 5):

So general relativistic n-body problem is not very studied in the community, but it has a bit of a renewal interest. Then I am not aware of public software, but there is a few group which have solution which kind of works:

- [3D Simulation of Spindle Gravitational Collapse of a Collisionless Particle System](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07906)
- [Black Hole Formation from the Collision of Plane-Fronted Gravitational Waves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11562)
- [The Limited Accuracy of Linearized Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05203)
- [General Relativistic Cosmological N-body Simulations I: time integration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07841)

Then you would see that the first NR nbody date from the 80s with the work of S. L. Shapiro and S. Teukolsky (85,86).